# WPF Adding menuitem to ContextMenu don't work when i use 'Task'

Tags: .net, wpf

I add items dynamicly to a `ContextMenu`,

it works very good,

Here is my code that works:

```
Dim Menu = MyContextMenu
Dim items = getItems()
For Each item in items
    Menu.Add(New MenuItem With{.Heder = item.Name}
Next
```

but when i want to take my data by async Task, like this:

```
Dim items  = await Task.Run(GetItems).ContinueWith(Function(x)x.Result)
```

the items are ok, the code runs ok. but in the UI I actualy dont see the new added items

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that code which add button invoked in UI thread.
You can choose from next:

- use Dispatcher.Invoke from your ContinuationCode (since obvious this task will be  executed in nonUI thread)
- use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() as parameter of ContinueWith.